# appium ios some buttons can not be inspected

Tags: ios, appium, uiaccessibility, inspector, safari-web-inspector

There is a custom button that we can't inspect by appium iOS in our application.

The problematic button has an Id. We can inspect it by Xcode accessibility inspector but we are not able to inspect it by appium web inspector.

Additionally we tried to click that button with the id that we took from Xcode accessibility inspector but it doesn't work. Appium console search it until it gets timeout.

How achieve this? Because this is an blocker issue for us. Any suggestions?

XCode Ver:9.2
MacOSx: 10.12.6
Appium:1.7.1

[image: XCode accessibility inspector view for the problematic button]

[image: Appium Web inspector view trying to inspect the on flexible]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) for elements inspection - it's an officially supported inspector for appium.

There is a possibility to sent `tap` action inside that inspector so that you will no for sure if *appium can interact with that button or not*.

Btw, sometimes custom elements may be not-accessible with appium, so it might be your case.